# When SysServer and Server Property Don't Match

Tags: sql-server

[Pinal suggests removing and adding the correct name](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/04/24/sql-server-error-while-enabling-cdc-on-a-table-the-specified-server-is-invalid-valid-values-are-returned-by-sp_helpserver/) based on the below difference discrepancy to fix this CDC error.  That may be correct for a solution, but would this affect anything else?  I tested an ADO connection to both connection instances and they both work, but I'm curious if there will be anything else negatively impacted by his solution.

The code that shows a difference between the two:

```
SELECT CONVERT(SYSNAME,SERVERPROPERTY('SERVERNAME')) 
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysservers
```

One being fully qualified, the other not.  Again, the ADO connection can hit both, but CDC is negatively impact by this.

His solution is like:

```
sp_dropserver 'domain\instance'
GO
sp_addserver 'full.domain.dom\instance', 'local'
GO
```

Would that cause connection issues, outside ADO - since I've confirmed ADO still connects to both instance names and types.

Answer (score 2):

`master.dbo.sysservers` is a deprecated. You should use `sys.servers`.

If you change your server name after installing sql server then you have to make the entry in `master.sys.servers` which can be done by `sp_dropserver` and `sp_addserver`